# Using MapReduce to read the files within a directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce, emr, amazon-emr

My S3 directory is

```
/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/xx/file1
/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/xx/file2
/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/xx/file3
/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/yy/file4
/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/yy/file5
/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/yy/file6
```

How my mapreduce program to read these files on S3?

Comment: Clarify what's intended by the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one input path you do the following:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/xx/"));
```

For two input paths, you do the following:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/xx/"));
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/sssssss/xxxxxx/rrrrrr/yy/"));
```

or use `addInputPaths()`. See [the documentation of `FileInputPath`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#addInputPaths(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,%20java.lang.String)) (depending on your version of Hadoop) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified by the following way :-

```
FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(conf, args[0]);
```

You just need to give the base path of the s3 dir and not the exact location of each and every file.
It will go to the last dir which contains file.